# jsonpath_rw for Python: How to navigate relatively?

Tags: python, json, jsonpath

I have a configuration database stored in a json file. This file is read from disk, parsed by Pythons *json* library and stored in a variable called `json`.

Now I'm investigating *jsonpath_rw* to build more readable path expressions then writing pure Python code to access multiple nested dicts and arrays.

Here is my current code:

```
# select all UART device serial numbers
exprSerial = parse('FPGAList.[*].UART.Serial')

#for serial in UART serial list
for match in exprSerial.find(json):
  print("Match: " + match.value + "    Path:" + str(match.full_path))

  if (match.value == USBSerial):
    #exprUART = match.full_path.Descendants) #under construction
```

The first expression lists all UART device serial numbers. The result is displayed on screen and working. Regarding the online documentation, I can print out the full path of the matching object by accessing `match.full_path`. This is a *jsonpath* object. If I call `str(..)` on it, it's transformed into a readable string.

Next, my code compares the value with a given serial number. If it's true, I would like to check some other parameters for safety: e.g. `USBDeviceVendor`. This key is also stored in the json file on the same hierarchy level.

My goal is it to construct a new jsonpath relative to `match.full_path` to access `USBDeviceVendor`.

**Bad solution:** `exprVendor = parse(str(match.full_path) + "..USBDeviceVendor")`

**Is it possible to extend `match.full_path` like `match.full_path.relative("..USBDeviceVendor")`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to go up one level and then back down. Rather than look for the matching descendants of the current result.

Use `` `parent` ``:

```
parse('`parent`.USBDeviceVendor').find(match)
```

Consider:

```
>>> import jsonpath_rw as jp
>>> obj = {'y':{'x':1,'g':{'t':0}}}
>>> jp.parse('`parent`.g').find(jp.parse("y.x").find(obj)[0])[0].value
{'t': 0}
```

Otherwise:

```
parse("`this`..USBDeviceVendor").find(match)
```

Consider:

```
>>> import jsonpath_rw as jp
>>> obj = {'y':{'x':{'g':{'t':0}}}}
>>> jp.parse("`this`..t").find(jp.parse("y.x").find(obj)[0])[0].value
0
```